# can't get $emit to pass prop to parent in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm making a todo app to better understand Vue and ran into a snag.

I've gone through several StackOverflow questions and the Vuejs forum, but I'm not understanding what I'm doing incorrectly.

The problem stems from the `to-do-item` Component Template:

```
  <button 
    @click="$emit('remove-item', {{item.id}} )">
    Remove
  </button>
```

If I replace `$emit` with a component method that doesn't call `$emit` it works fine, but when I use `$emit` (even in a local component function) it refuses to render.

I'm not sure why this is. Here's the rest of my code:

```js
Vue.component("todo-item", {
  props:["item"],
  template: `
<li>{{ item.text }} 
  <button 
    @click="$emit('remove-item', {{item.id}} )">
    Remove
   </button>
</li>`
})

let vm = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    text: "",
    todos: []
  },
  methods: {
    getID: (function() {
      let id = 0;
      return function() {
        return id++;
      }
    }()),
    addTodo: function() {
      this.todos.push({id: this.getID(), text: this.text});
      this.text = "";
    },
    remove: function(remove_id) {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(({id}) => id != remove_id);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="container">
    <main>
      <ul>
         <todo-item
                    v-for="todo in todos"
                    :item="todo"
                    @remove-item="remove"
                   >
          </todo-item>
      </ul>
    </main>
  <div id="add-field">
  <input v-model="text" /> <button id="add" @click="addTodo">Add Todo</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use template syntax inside a javascript-executed attribute:

```
<button 
    @click="$emit('remove-item', {{item.id}} )">
```

Fix that, and it should work:

```js
Vue.component("todo-item", {
  props:["item"],
  template: `
<li>{{ item.text }} 
  <button 
    @click="$emit('remove-item', item.id )">
    Remove
   </button>
</li>`
})

let vm = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    text: "",
    todos: []
  },
  methods: {
    getID: (function() {
      let id = 0;
      return function() {
        return id++;
      }
    }()),
    addTodo: function() {
      this.todos.push({id: this.getID(), text: this.text});
      this.text = "";
    },
    remove: function(remove_id) {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(({id}) => id != remove_id);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="container">
    <main>
      <ul>
         <todo-item
             v-for="todo in todos"
             :item="todo"
             @remove-item="remove"
             >
          </todo-item>
      </ul>
    </main>
  <div id="add-field">
      <input v-model="text" /> 
      <button id="add" @click="addTodo">Add Todo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I figured it would be something simple but I was banging my head against a wall! Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help